# gh-pages react deploy not finding js bundle

Tags: reactjs, github, webpack, github-pages

I've been following [this gh-pages react guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages), but basically I installed gh-pages as a dev dependency, I've updated my package.json to include the correct homepage and predeploy/deploy scripts (I had to change the deploy script to target `dist` instead of `build` folder as my build script uploads to a `dist` folder).

When I deploy, the `gh-pages` branch does receive a commit and it does publish without error.

My problem is that my index.html script src is `/main.bundle.js` instead of `/[reponame]/main.bundle.js` - because gh-pages creates a base url like `https://[username].github.io/[reponame]/`

I see in other people's example, like https://gitname.github.io/react-gh-pages/ for example, it properly uses the base url `<script defer="defer" src="/react-gh-pages/static/js/main.a700d49d.js"></script>`, I see that they are using `react-scripts` to build where I am using `webpack`. Do I need to do something extra to make webpack work properly here?

The relevant part of my package.json looks like:

```
  "homepage": "https://{gitname}.github.io/{gitrepo}",
  "scripts": {
      "predeploy": "npm run build",
      "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
      "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
```

Comment: Looks like the key bit is to set `"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app"` in package.json - although I'm not sure whether you've got that set correctly or not.

Comment: @Joundill - I've added some links, I feel like I've checked the hompage several times and tried it with and without a trailing `/`

Comment: You need to tell Webpack what the [publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) is for assets. `homepage` only works for sites built with create-react-app

Comment: @Phil - I've changed my `webpack.common.js` file line to set `ASSET_PATH` to `/jbq` and it seems to be working. Thanks! I'll just have to play around with it to make sure it's not breaking other places.

Comment: You might want that in prod only. If the suggested link answers your question, please accept the duplicate